# Retrieving AWS lambdas tags causes ValidationException: 'resource' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must satisfy regular expression pattern: arn

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services

I'm trying to print out AWS lambda's tags in the pipeline. I use the commands:

```
functions=$(aws lambda list-functions --region "$region" --query "Functions[?starts_with(FunctionName, 'some-name-pattern')].[FunctionName,FunctionArn]" --output text)
while read -r function_name function_arn
do
    echo "Function: ${function_name}"
    echo "ARN: ${function_arn}"
    aws lambda list-tags --region "$region" --resource "$function_arn" --query 'Tags' --output json
    echo
done <<< "$functions"
```

All list-tags calls except the last one are responded with error: "An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the ListTags operation: 1 validation error detected: Value 'arn:aws:lambda:eu-west-1:215741029594:function:function-name' at 'resource' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must satisfy regular expression pattern: arn:(aws[a-zA-Z-]*)?:lambda:[a-z]{2}((-gov)|(-iso(b?)))?-[a-z]+-\d{1}:\d{12}:function:[a-zA-Z0-9-*]+(:($LATEST|[a-zA-Z0-9-*]+))?". The last one returns the expected tags. I verified with online regex tool, the ARNs matches the required pattern. When I call list-tags with some of the failed ARNs I get expected response. I tried to change the default timeout settings for connecting and reading operations.
Can anybody suggest what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

We used another approach:

```
aws resourcegroupstaggingapi get-resources --region "$region" --query "ResourceTagMappingList[?contains(ResourceARN, '${PREFIX}')]" --resource-type-filters "lambda"
```